# MyBatis Select JSON Clob into MAP<String , String> as a resultset

Tags: sql, mybatis, ibatis

I have a table, lets say User which has a column as Userdetails.
and Userdetails is of type Clob and contain a JSON as a data 
like next

```
{name:'ABC', add:'XYZ'......}
```

So I want to get the column value resultSet of below as a Map.

```
 select Userdetails from User
```

Answer (score 1):

You must create your own `TypeHandler` for that. It is explained in the official doc how to do it: [type handler](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers).

Why?

> Whenever MyBatis sets a parameter on a PreparedStatement or retrieves
>   a value from a ResultSet, a TypeHandler is used to retrieve the value
>   in a means appropriate to the Java type. The following table describes
>   the default TypeHandlers.

In general, common typeHandlers are implemented, but in special cases like next you need to do it.

How?

> You can override the type handlers or create your own to deal with
>   unsupported or non-standard types. To do so, implement the interface
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeHandler or extend the convenience class
>   org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler and optionally map it to a JDBC
>   type.

And finally, you need to add the new type handler to your configuration:

```
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->
<typeHandlers>
  <typeHandler handler="your.pckg.ClobTypeHandler" />
</typeHandlers>
```

---

In your case, you can just extends directly the existing handler `BaseTypeHandler` using as generic `Map<String, Object>`.
For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Clob;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;


public class ClobJsonTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<Map<String, Object>> {


    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Map<String, Object> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        final String parameterString = mapToJson(parameter);
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(parameterString);
        ps.setCharacterStream(i, reader, parameterString.length());
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        String value = "";
        Clob clob = rs.getClob(columnName);
        if (clob != null) {
            int size = (int) clob.length();
            value = clob.getSubString(1L, size);
        }

        return jsonToMap(value);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String value = "";
        Clob clob = rs.getClob(columnIndex);
        if (clob != null) {
            int size = (int) clob.length();
            value = clob.getSubString(1L, size);
        }

        return jsonToMap(value);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        String value = "";
        Clob clob = cs.getClob(columnIndex);
        if (clob != null) {
            int size = (int) clob.length();
            value = clob.getSubString(1L, size);
        }

        return jsonToMap(value);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String from) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(from, HashMap.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }

    private String mapToJson(Map<String, Object> from) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(from);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error();
        }
    }
}
```